# Convert user input value into string in QML

Tags: qt, qml

I have my function checkPinCode() that will check the user entered pincode with the actual pincode.

Here I am facing a problem to get the user entered input value into string. Since the text field has the pincode as string. So i need to convert the user entered input also to a string during the comparison. How can I convert my `pincodeSetting.value` to a string. And I am new to QML. It would be nice if some one helps.

```
function checkPinCode() {
        var pinOk = (pinCodeEdit.text === NTModelDBCpp.systemSettings.pincodeSetting.value)
        if (false === pinOk) {
            pinCodeEdit.text       = "";
            invalidPinText.visible = true;
        }
        return pinOk;
```

Comment: What type has your `pincodeSetting.value`?

Comment: I  think it is int type.

Comment: Try [`pincodeSetting.value.toString()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_number.asp)

Comment: No, it didnt work

Comment: What doesn't work? If it is a `int`, `toString()` does work. To investigate, what does not work, use console.log(...) to print different values (e.g. pincodeSetting.value.toString(), pinCodeEdit.text etc.) or use the debugger.

Comment: `var pinOk = (pinCodeEdit.text === String(NTModelDBCpp.systemSettings.pincodeSetting.value))`?

Answer (score 0):

move this function(`checkPinCode`) in your c++ class and do your work in your c++ code

```
bool NTModelDBCpp::checkPinCode(int pincode){
        return pincode === value;        
}
```

and use in qml.the convertion will done automatically.

```
if(NTModelDBCpp.checkPinCode(yourText){
}
```

define the checkPinCode as static method in your .h c++ file